# Position changes after Ionic build Android | Android | Ionic | ionicons

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework, icons

I'm developing an app using the Ionic framework.

I created 2 buttons which work good on my `ionic serve`, but after `ionic build android` they are totally unaligned.

```
<a href="#/app/ketels-list" class="circle button-custom">
            <div class="dark">
              <i class="icon ion-android-notifications placeholder-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <h6 class="master">Vind de <b>betekenis</b> van <b>foutcodes!</b></h6>
          </a>
```

CSS

```
.welcomescreen #welcomecontent .circle{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 2.5vh auto 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    box-shadow: 0px;
}
.welcomescreen #welcomecontent .dark{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #4f76ad;
    box-shadow: 0px;
    padding: 23px 27.5px;
}
.welcomescreen #welcomecontent .button-custom {
    color: #4f76ad ;
    border: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.welcomescreen #welcomecontent .button-custom.active, .welcomescreen #welcomecontent .button-custom:hover, .welcomescreen #welcomecontent .button-custom:focus {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #4f76ad;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .welcomescreen #welcomecontent i {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

I tried all sorts of center tricks but they all seem to fail.

[image]

Comment: This is a wild guess, but your problem seems to be the circle margin is dependant on viewport height: `margin: 2.5vh auto 25px;` Use `px`, `em` or `rem` and it will (most likely) render the same on both. If it's not this, you need to create a [mcve] to get proper help (at least from me) with this.

Comment: But this is the outer margin, so shouldn't matter i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should center your icons:

```
.welcomescreen #welcomecontent .dark {
    position: relative;
}
.welcomescreen #welcomecontent i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes! this works! thanks! what does the transform exactly do ?

Comment: `transform` transforms. The trick is using `%` in `transform`. `transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)` moves any `positioned` (relative/absolute) element with exactly half of its height up and half of its width left. Combined with `left: 50%` and `top:50%` (which are relative to the closest `positioned` (relative/absolute) element, makes for a perfect vertical and horizontal alignment. The only condition is that the child's dimensions are not bigger than the parent's. When this happens, the alignment breaks under certain conditions.